# How to register a view which is available only in functional tests

Tags: plone

I am creating functional tests for a frameworkish Plone addon which interacts with other addons through views (BrowserViews).

How one can register a view which is available only in functional testing for testing purposes? I'd like to mock up the integration point and see if it gives good view lookups and calls.

Answer (score 2):

I did this with following:

```
def setUp(self):
        self.app = self.layer['app']
        self.portal = self.layer['portal']

        # Register view directly by pushing it to zope.component multi-adapter registry

        zope.component.provideAdapter(
            # Our class
            factory=TestingRedirectHandler,
            # (context, request) layers for multiadapter lookup
            # We provide None as layers are not used
            adapts=(None, None),
            # All views are registered as IBrowserView interface
            provides=zope.publisher.interfaces.browser.IBrowserView,
            # View name
            name='redirect_handler')

        browser = Browser(self.portal)
        browser.handleErrors = False
        browser.raiseHttpErrors = False
        self.browser = browser

    def tearDown(self):
        """
        """
        # Dynamically unregister a view
        gsm = zope.component.getGlobalSiteManager()
        gsm.unregisterAdapter(factory=TestingRedirectHandler,
                              required=(None, None),
                              provided=zope.publisher.interfaces.browser.IBrowserView,
                              name="redirect_handler")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a tests folders, you can create a `configure.zcml` file there and register a view there (python file should be there for consistency) and that should be it.